# How to assign images to a given selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want users to select a price from a select , and depending on the price selected, an image or another to show up.

I created a Prices Table , with 2 columns: price (integer) , and price_image (string).

#### Then, I created a column in the Foods table called :price_id ( integer ), and made 2 asociations:

```
Prices has_many :foods, and Foods has_one :price.
```

Everything OK till there. I can show up the price_id of @food in my view.

*I need to tell Rails that:*

**If price_id = 1, then show price_image for price_id = 1
If price_id = 2, then show price_image for price_id = 2... and so on.**

What am I missing? Thanks a lot

#### Food Controller (Is in the index action where I will need the price images to show up):

```
  def index
      @addictfood = Addictfood.last
      @food = Food.last
      @foods = Food.by_category(params[:category_id])
      @price = Prices.find(params[:price_id])
  end
```

#### My view

```
<div class="panel semi_margin_bottom food_card">
    <%= image_tag @food.food_image_url(:food_small), class: "radius" %>
    <h5> <%= @food.name %> </h5>
    <span class="small"><i class="icon-list"></i> <%= @food.ingredients %></span>
    <span class="medium block textright"><%= @food.price_id %></span>
</div>
```

#### Error in Foods controller: Couldn't find Prices without an ID

Thanks a lot

Comment: i think it would be `params[:prices_id]` in your index action since your model is named prices

Comment: I just renamed the table to :price to avoid confusions, but still doesn't work

Comment: Yes, Couldn't find Price without an ID. I just want to know, 1.) How do I need to call @food. in order to get it's price_image from the associated table? 2.) Do I need price in my Food #index action controller?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `price belongs_to food`? And also model classname should be singular not plural.

Comment: @Pavan I've changed the model name to singular...but still getting this error:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: prices.food_id: SELECT  "prices".* FROM "prices"  WHERE "prices"."food_id" = ?  ORDER BY "prices"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: Your associations are wrong. It should be `Price belongs_to :food`, and `Food has_one :price` and you should be creating `food_id` in `prices` table not `price_id` in `foods` table.

Comment: Its looking better, the only thing is that now it says undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass when I put <%= @food.price.price %>. Do I need to touch controller?

Comment: @Pavan, but I can't understand why do I have wrong the associations. When I create a new Food, I need to select a price for it, how can I do this if I don't have a price_id to select?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

`I can't understand why do I have wrong the associations. When I create a new Food, I need to select a price for it, how can I do this if I don't have a price_id to select?`

What you need is a [**`has_and_belongs_to_many`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association.

So your models would look like:

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foods
end

class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :prices
end
```

Coming back to the way you have declared your associations, you have `Price has_many :foods, and Food has_one :price.`

When you have `Food has_one :price` rails look for `price_id in your foods table` and for `Price has_many :foods` for this also rails will look for `price_id` in your foods table. Therefore instead of using **Price has_many :foods** it'll be **`Price belongs_to :food`** which will make rails look for **`food_id in your prices table`**. For more details refer to [**`rail guides`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I still couldn't solve it but I could achieve what I wanted just making a price (string) column in my Foods table, and putting if conditionals: <% if @food.price === "2€" %> , show me this image. I know it's not the best way to do it, but for now it works perfectly. Thanks!